# Why CERT standard PRE00-CPP says "Avoid defining macros"

Tags: c++, c, macros

According to the [CERT standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/PRE00-CPP.+Avoid+defining+macros) ***Object-like macros can be dangerous because their uses are not subject to the language scope rules***. Can any one please explain with an example How it is problematic. say for example I have an Object-like macro `#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024`

Comment: I imagine their complaint is just as you pasted: "are not subject to the language scope rules"... meaning that for example, you could #define within a function, but it's accessible outside the function as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// file a.hpp
#define SOME_MACRO 42

// file some/nested/dir/really/far/in/x.hpp
#define SOME_MACRO 13
```

Kaboom. This would have easily been avoided using any kind of scope, e.g.

```
struct X { static unsigned const value = 42; };
struct Y { static unsigned const value = 13; };
```

Now you can access `X::value` and `Y::value`. Same goes for namespaces:

```
namespace a { struct X; }
namespace b { struct X; }
```

Answer (score 3):

C/C++ preprocessing is just manipulating/generating text, no language rules involved.

Comment: If you #define X = 1 and have a source line int x = X; the compiler will see x = 1.

Answer (score 3):

A classic example is

```
#define max 1234

...
class A
{
   int arr[100];
 public:
      ...
   int max() { ... find highest in arr ... }
};
```

This won't compile.

Comment: So please correct me if I am wrong this means that as a object macro does not have a scope when we declare max as a function compiler encounters max already defined so this is an ambiguity ??

Comment: That's one reason why I hate windows.h

Comment: The preprocessor (which parses `#define`, etc) will replace `max` with `1234` wherever it is, no matter what the context is, and before the compiler gets to see the code. The compiler will then complain that `int 1234()` is not a valid function name [quite likely not quite so obvious as that!]. And it doesn't matter if we put namespace, struct or something else around the `#define max 1234` line - it will have the same effect still. Only way to avoid it is `#undef max`, but then we can't do that if we actually needed the constant somewhere later on.

Comment: @SanyamGoel it's worse than that. preprocessing takes place before the compiler goes to work, so `max` will have been replaced by `1234`

Comment: Yes thanks @MatsPetersson and nijansen understood the concept :)