# Why using macros in C++ is considered wrong ? and usage of C++ standard libraries

Tags: c++, c

Most people on stackoverflow say its horrible to use macros in C++.
    I don't get the idea behind this. I know theres alternatives in C++ 
    but why its "wrong" ?

Comment: Post some source/link, where you found that?

Comment: Using them is not wrong, using them wrongly is wrong (huh...)

Comment: There are many questions tackling this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-preprocessor-macros-are-evil-and-what-is-the-real-alternative-c11 is a good start

Comment: Just two questions that basically ask the identical thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230719/why-cert-standard-pre00-cpp-says-avoid-defining-macros/18230840#18230840 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373782/are-there-any-good-uses-of-macros/18373921#18373921

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319452/are-all-macros-evil is one more, a search for "why are macros evil" yields many more blog posts n such

Comment: Macros are not evil (as well as goto and the other "scary" stuff). The only true evil is the incompetent coders.

Answer (score 2):

Let see what Stroustrup says:

### [So, what's wrong with using macros?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro)

> Macros do not obey the C++ scope and type rules. This is often the
>   cause of subtle and not-so-subtle problems. Consequently, C++ provides
>   alternatives that fit better with the rest of C++, such as inline
>   functions, templates, and namespaces.

...

> And yes, I do know that there are things known as macros that doesn't
>   suffer the problems of C/C++ preprocessor macros. However, I have no
>   ambitions for improving C++ macros. Instead, I recommend the use of
>   facilities from the C++ language proper, such as inline functions,
>   templates, constructors (for initialization), destructors (for
>   cleanup), exceptions (for exiting contexts), etc.